# Simple Nested Dynamic Route

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to use a modal as a nested route to perform a task for each object. For example `'/objects/2'` route has a `<nuxt-child/>` component in it for adding comments in a modal with the route path `'/objects/2/add-comment'`.

I have the directory structure below but this doesn't create nested routes. What am I doing wrong?

```
pages/
--| objects/
----| _id/
------| index.vue
------| add-comment.vue
----| index.vue
```

resulting routes.js is flat:

```
routes: [{
    path: "/objects/:id?",
    component: _45173a6a,
    name: "objects-id"
  }, {
    path: "/objects/:id?/add-comment",
    component: _14a12353,
    name: "object-id-add-comment"
  }, {
...
```

Comment: Got the latest nuxtjs with child routes too, but my router.js file looks exactly like yours, but everything works as it's supposed to do

Comment: But the add comment page is not treated as a child component, behind the modal, it's blank, instead of showing object details.

Comment: If you want to utilize the `<nuxt-child/>` component, then try putting a new file at the same level as the `objects` folder, called `objects.vue`, and utilize the child in here

Comment: But then `objects.vue` wouldn't have the parameter `id`. I think I figured it out though. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

This was the directory structure I needed:

```
pages/
--| objects/
----| _id/
------| add-comment.vue
----| _id.vue
```

which results in a nested route config:

```js
routes: [{
    path: "/objects/:id?",
    component: _45173a6a,
    name: "objects-id"
    children: [{
        path: "add-comment",
        component: _14a12353,
        name: "object-id-add-comment"
    }],
},
...
```